# if counter reaches max count counter++ else counter = 0 in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, max

okay so i want if my counter reaches the maximum count, it starts over, with the default counter number which is 0 here is my code:

```
var picCount = 0; // global
 var maxCount = 4;
 //Pictures, to add more then 4 pics, add var picFive = "link to image here", var picSix ="bla", you get it.. add in picArray ,picFive and ,picSix
 //To change the time delay, change it at the body onload and on the setTimeout
 var picOne = "http://screenshots.nl.sftcdn.net/nl/scrn/3342000/3342167/modloader-for-minecraft-02-700x406.jpg"
 var picTwo = "http://media.moddb.com/images/downloads/1/31/30912/minecraft_blox.png"
 var picThree = "http://www.mupload.nl/img/rl6zeofbb.png"
 var picFour = "http://www.mupload.nl/img/rl6zeofbb.png"

 var picArray = [picOne, picTwo, picThree, picFour]

 //  
 // gets next picture in array
     function nextPic() { // check if adding 1 exceeds number of pics in array
         if (picCount.length < maxCount.length) {
             picCount = (picCount + 1 < picArray.length) ? picCount + 1 : 5000;
             // build the image to write to page using the new pic reference
             var build = '<img border="0" src="' + picArray[picCount] + '" width="649">\n';
             document.getElementById("imgHolder").innerHTML = build;
             // repeat this every    10 seconds. 
             setTimeout('nextPic()', 10 * 1000) //setTimeout is here
         } else {
             picCount = (picCount - maxCount < picArray.length) ? picCount + 1 : 5000;
             // build the image to write to page using the new pic reference
             var build = '<img border="0" src="' + picArray[picCount] + '" width="649">\n';
             document.getElementById("imgHolder").innerHTML = build;
             // repeat this every    10 seconds. 
             setTimeout('nextPic()', 10 * 1000) //setTimeout is here
         }
     }
```

okay so i hope you guys can help me with this..

Comment: That's a lot of (badly formatted) code to demonstrate a counter.

Comment: Your title answers it.

Comment: `setTimeout('nextPic()',10 * 1000)//setTimeout is here` best comment ever

Comment: You have so many useless comments!

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of messy code.
My fix for an implementation would probably look something like this:

```
var currentPic = 0;
var picOne = "http://screenshots.nl.sftcdn.net/nl/scrn/3342000/3342167/modloader-for-minecraft-02-700x406.jpg"
var picTwo = "http://media.moddb.com/images/downloads/1/31/30912/minecraft_blox.png"
var picThree = "http://www.mupload.nl/img/rl6zeofbb.png"
var picFour = "http://www.mupload.nl/img/rl6zeofbb.png"

var picArray= [picOne,picTwo,picThree,picFour]

function nextPic()  {
    if (currentPic < picArray.length) {currentPic++;}
    else {currentPic = 0;}

    var build='<img border="0" src="'+picArray[currentPic]+'" width="649">';
    document.getElementById("imgHolder").innerHTML=build;
    // repeat this every    10 seconds. 
    setTimeout('nextPic()',10 * 1000)//setTimeout is here
}
```

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it proves to answer your question/solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Despite many other issues which I am sure are present in your code, I believe this line is the cause of your particular problem addressed in the question:

```
if (picCount.length < maxCount.length) {
```

`maxCount` and `picCount` are just numbers. They do not have a length property. Change it to this:

```
if (picCount < maxCount) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentPic = 0;
var picArray= ["http://screenshots.nl.sftcdn.net/nl/scrn/3342000/3342167/modloader-for-minecraft-02-700x406.jpg",
               "http://media.moddb.com/images/downloads/1/31/30912/minecraft_blox.png",
               "http://www.mupload.nl/img/rl6zeofbb.png",
               "http://www.mupload.nl/img/rl6zeofbb.png"];

function nextPic()  {
    (currentPic < picArray.length) ? currentPic++ : currentPic = 0;
    var build='<img border="0" src="'+picArray[currentPic]+'" width="649">';
    document.getElementById("imgHolder").innerHTML=build;
}

setTimeout('nextPic()',10 * 1000);
```

I made a few changes that make your code cleaner. 
Some tips:

- No need to store your image URLs in vars before putting them in the array. Just initialize your array with them.
- Don't repeat yourself. Whenever you find yourself using the exact same code in multiple places, you probably need to rethink how you are approaching the problem.
- Look up the "ternary operator". In my opinion it makes simple conditional statements easier to read.
- No need to use maxCount - the max count will be the length of your picArray.
- Although not usually required, try to end all statements with a semicolon.
- Don't mind the elitist attitude some people have, but at the same time, try to research as much as you can before asking a question.